# How to securely connect cable to AXA Quattro dynamo?

Tags: repair, lighting, electric-power, electric-bike

See the image: *How do I securely attach the cable to the [dynamo](http://www.axa-stenman.com/en/bicycle-components/lighting/dynamos/quattro/)?*

[image: Annotated photo of dynamo and cable]

I tried the obvious, threaded the cable through one of the holes in the plastic cover, and pressed the cover snugly onto the socket. This was OK for some rides, but in the end the plastic cover fell off and the cable is loose.

Comment: Assemble it as in the manual, and cover with electrical tape tightly.

Comment: Can't tell for sure from the photo, but it looks as if there are a couple of screws there.  One would think you're supposed to loosen a screw, slide the wire under, and then tighten.

Comment: @Batman There was no manual included that explains how to do the electric connection.

Comment: @DanielRHicks There are no screws for the electric connection. The plastic cover has two knobs, each one with a hole for a cable.

Comment: Isn't there any provision for strain relief?  And isn't there an overall cover for that end of the unit?

Comment: @DanielRHicks There are just the two little plastic covers with two holes in each (and one of the covers is lost now). Maybe I'll just solder the cable to one of the four contacts. Possibly, the problem is the cable, the core of which is quite thick.

Comment: If you're using the spec'd parts the wire isn't the problem. There is either a push in connection somewhere or there is a screw that secures the wire. Did you install this yourself or did a shop do it?

Comment: Well, it's impossible to tell what you've got there, but it sounds like it was not properly assembled.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhjA4K3rT_w seems to be an instructional video by the manufacturers. Since one of the covers is gone, you may want to get another one, reinstall it and then add some electrical tape to prevent it from coming loose.

Comment: @WTHarper It's a push-in connection, there are no screws for the electric connection. My father got the dynamo from a shop. As said before, there were no instructions concerning connecting wiring included in the package. These dynamos are very popular over here in Europe.

Comment: @Batman Although certainly not by the manufacturer and for a different dynamo, this is an interesting video. Unfortunately, in the part where the instructor does the wiring, there are some cuts, and it's hard to see what exactly he’s doing. He mentions that he bends the wires over — perhaps I’ll try that.

Comment: In any case, if they're popular,  you should be able to take it to a shop that sells these and they should be able to explain the wiring hookup (and if you can document it better, you may help someone else in the future!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the [shop](http://www.zweirad-fuhr.de/) where the dynamo was bought, and let me explain
how to connect a cable. My summary:

1. Unplug the plastic cover from the correct socket: One is for ground,
   one for phase.
2. Thread the dismantled tip through one of the two holes in the cover.
   The length of the dismantled tip should be so that part of it
   protrudes below.
3. Bend the protruding piece by 180°. The plastic cover is recessed to
   accommodate the piece. See the photo below for the final result.
4. Press the plastic cover on the socket.

When posting the question, I had missed step three.

[image: Photo of plastic cover with cable]

Comment: Hey could you post a photo?

Comment: @Deesbek Photo added.

Comment: Just for reference, Shimano hub dynamos use a very similar trick, just that there, a plastic sleeve is put around this black thingie and the whole shebang is plugged onto the dynamo's contacts.